# How to make tasks in ProcessPoolExecutor behave like daemon process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio

Python 3.6.6

Here is code:

```
import asyncio
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


executor_processes = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)


def calculate():
    while True:
        print("while")
        time.sleep(1)


async def async_method():
    loop_ = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop_.run_in_executor(executor_processes, calculate)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("finish sleep")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(async_method())
    print("main_thread is finished")
```

Output:

> while
>   finish sleep
>   main_thread is finished
>   while
>   while
>   ...

I expect that child process will be terminated like in case when Process is spawned with daemon property like:

```
import asyncio
import time
import multiprocessing


def calculate():
    while True:
        print("while")
        time.sleep(1)


async def async_method():
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=calculate)
    proc.daemon = True
    proc.start()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("finish sleep")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(async_method())
    print("main_thread is finished")
```

Output:

> while
>   finish sleep
>   main_thread is finished

**Question:** how to change `loop_.run_in_executor(executor_processes, calculate)` behavior to "daemon-like"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you show is clearly just a small example to demonstrate what you are hoping to achieve. We don't know your real-world task/problem. But honestly, I'm not convinced you are on the correct path here.

`ProcessPoolExecutor` is part of the `concurrent.futures` standard library package. It returns a [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=processpoolexecutor#future-objects) to the caller upon invoking `submit()`. That `Future` is a proxy for a result of a computation that has not yet completed. It's a promise; although that term is technically not quite correct in this context. See the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) for the distinction.

This implies, that the computation is *expected* to complete in finite time and yield a result.
That is why the `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `ProcessPoolExecutor` implementations in Python don't allow you to spawn daemonic workers. Demanding a promise for a result that you don't actually want fulfilled does not make much sense.

How can you still achieve your goal?

**1 - Subclass `ProcessPoolExecutor`?**
 You can intercept the creation and start of new processes to sneak in a `p.daemon = True` in [`_adjust_process_count()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py#L587-L593). However, since `concurrent.futures` is not designed with indefinitely running tasks in mind, this won't help much. Unlike [`multiprocessing`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/multiprocessing/util.py#L315-L318), `concurrent.futures.process` defines an [exit handler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py#L96) that doesn't consider daemonic processes. It just tries to `join()` everything, and that can take some time for infinite loops.

**2 - Define your own exit handler!**
 You could do what both, `multiprocessing` and `concurrent.futures.process` do: define an exit handler, that cleans up when your Python process is about to shut down. [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) can help with that:

```
import atexit

executor_processes = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)

def calculate():
    while True:
        print("while")
        time.sleep(1)

def end_processes():
    [proc.terminate() for proc in multiprocessing.active_children()]

async def async_method():
    [...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    atexit.register(end_processes)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    [...]
```

**Note:** This will terminate all child processes that are active by the end of the process. If there are child processes that you want to shut down gracefully, keep a handle and do that before the instructions in your code end.
 Also note that processes can refuse to honor [`terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing.Process.terminate). [`kill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing.Process.kill) is your *last* resort.